# Python JSON output new line

Tags: python, json

Hello I am working on a ISS tracker using open notify api. However I want the JSON data being outputted onto a new line each time. My current code spits out the data all onto one line. Any good way of making the output usable? Thank you!

```
import requests
import json
import time
URL = "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json"

filename = 'store.json'
#sending get request and saving the response as response object
i = 0
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    #time for API calls
    while i<11:
        save = {}
        r = requests.get(url = URL)
        data = r.json()

        save['time'] = data['timestamp']
        save['latitude'] = data['iss_position']['latitude']
        save['longitude'] = data['iss_position']['longitude']
        json.dump(save, file_object)
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indent` keyword argument in order to have the json saved in a formatted state.

For example:

```
json.dump(save, file_object, indent=4)
```

from the python docs:

> If indent is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, negative, or "" will only insert newlines. None (the default) selects the most compact representation. Using a positive integer indent indents that many spaces per level. If indent is a string (such as "\t"), that string is used to indent each level.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)

Comment: The OP's problem isn't with indentation/human readability, but that all JSON outputs immediately follow after one another, rendering the final file unparsable. A simple line break between each JSON output would solve the problem like @jasonharper says, effectively making the output file in JSONL format.